# Get the "many" entries of a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, serialization

I have a one-to-many relationship in eloquent declared.

- One serial has more episodes, one episode has one serial.

I understood how to retrieve `serial` data for an episode:

```
TheEpisode::where('id', '=', $id)->take(1)->with('TheParts', 'TheAuthor')
```

But how I do the same, do retrieve episodes of a TV serial?

```
`Table: TheSeries`
id      | SerialName 
---------------------
1       | Zootopia
2       | Moana
3       | Toy Story

`Table: TheEpisodes`
seriesID| episode
---------------------
1       | 10
2       | 10
3       | 10
1       | 11
2       | 11
2       | 12
```

I need all episodes of Moana TV serial (which should be episodes: 10,11,12)

How should I query it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get serial with all it's episodes using [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
Serial::where('id', $serialId)->with('episodes')->first();
```

Get all episodes:

```
TheEpisode::where('serial_id', $serialId)->get();
```